# How to find the maximum starred project within an github organization

Tags: github

How to find the maximum starred project (i.e. most popular) within an github organization containing many projects spanning multiple pages(e.g. https://github.com/foo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub web UI only offer sortable stars on [your Starred Projects page](https://github.com/stars?direction=desc&sort=stars) (see [sortable stars](https://github.com/blog/1410-sortable-stars))

That leaves you with the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) in order to:

- [list all the repos of an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)
- sort the JSON results by the "`stargazers_count`" field.

A bit [like this ruby script](https://gist.github.com/xoyip/10015258):

```rb
repos.each do |r|
  user, repo = r.split "/"
  info = nil

  # たまに404があったりするので適当にrescue
  begin
    info = Github.repos.find user, repo
  rescue
    next
  end
  count = info["stargazers_count"]
  result["#{r}"] = count
end

# スター数が多い順にソートして出力
# Sort order most Stars to output
result.sort_by{|k, v| -v}.each do |k, v|
  printf "%4d: #{k}\n", v
end
```

Comment: I needed this sorted by an Organization, but I guess can use this information to do this via an API

Comment: Yes, that is what the first link is for: listing the repos of an organization. The shows how to sort the resulting list.